# Force IconizedObject to evaluate without Part or ToBoxes

Tags: front-end, iconize

I enjoy the new [`Iconize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Iconize.html) feature, but one major complaint I have is that it's difficult to extract the value if the `IconizedObject` had instead been assigned to a variable. E.g.:

```
myRes = Iconize@Range[10]

myRes + 1 // Head

Plus
```

I can force evaluation through the box mechanism:

```
ToExpression@ToBoxes@myRes + 1
```

Or via the first argument to the `IconizedObject`:

```
myRes[[1]] + 1

{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
```

But both of these feel clumsy and if the expression form of an `IconizedObject` changed the second could break.

Is there any built-in way to reparse the `IconizedObject` without `ToBoxes`?

Comment: The documentation says "The typeset output evaluates to the first argument of the result", so probably using `Part` or `First` is fine and future proof.

Comment: The idea is that it should go smoothly through ToExpression @* ToBoxes. And if you assume that `IconizedObject` can change this would be the last thing to change. Therefore, I don't know what do you expect :) p.s. you can have your object wrapper which typesets via IconizedObject but I guess you know and that is not what you want either.